# Is it true that $\biggl\|I-\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\biggr\|=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am following a proof in the text OPTIMIZATION THEORY AND METHODS a springer series by WENYU SUN and YA-XIANG YUAN. I come across what seems obvious that for a column vector  $v$, with dimension $n\times 1$, $$\biggl\|I-\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\biggr\|=1,$$ where $I$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and $\|.||$ is a matrix norm.

---

I try to verify it by considering a Frobenius norm, that is

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 \biggl\|I-\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\biggr\|_F& = \biggl (tr\biggl(I-\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\biggr)^T\biggl(I-\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\biggr)\biggl)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
& = \biggl (tr\biggl(I-\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\biggr)^2\biggr)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
& =tr\biggl(I-\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\biggr)\\
& =tr\bigl(I\bigr)-tr\biggr(\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\biggr)\\
& =n-\frac{1}{\|v\|^2} \|v\|^2\\
& =n-1
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

---

So, I do not what is the problem. Because in the text no specification of norm is given.  May be I have to change another matrix norm.

---

NOTE: A Frobenius matrix norm for any matrix $A$ is defined by 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
||A\|_F & = \biggl( \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|^2\biggr)^\frac{1}{2}\\
& = \biggl(tr(A^TA)\biggr)^\frac{1}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: With no context, the norm of a matrix is usually the operator 2-norm, that is, $\| A \| = \max_{\| x \|_2 = 1} \| A x \|$.

Comment: Are you sure that $\sqrt{tr(A^2)} = tr(A)$? I have my doubts...

Comment: @Ian you mean that with operator 2-norm the answer is 1?

Comment: The statement is not true for $n=1$.

Comment: @daw which $n$?

Comment: @HassanMuhammad The dimension, i.e. $I$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. It is clear from the answer by Batman below that the statement is true if and only if $n\geq 2$.

Comment: @AlexR - In general, $tr(A^2) \neq tr(A)^2$. Note that the trace of a matrix is the sum of the eigenvalues, and when you square a matrix, you square its eigenvalues. So if $\lambda_i$ is the i-th eigenvalue, what we're saying is $\lambda_1^2 + \ldots + \lambda_n^2 \neq (\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n)^2$. One trivial example is the 2x2 matrix with $1, -1$ on the diagonal and 0's elsewhere. Its trace is 0, but the square of this matrix is the identity matrix which has trace 2. And $\sqrt{2} \neq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

$P=I - \frac{v v^T}{v^T v}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $v^\perp$.

Proof: Clearly, $P$ is symmetric.

$P^2 = (I - \frac{v v^T}{v^T v}) (I - \frac{v v^T}{v^T v}) = I - 2 \frac{v v^T}{v^T v} + \frac{v v^T}{v^T v} \frac{v v^T}{v^T v} =  I - 2 \frac{v v^T}{v^T v} + \frac{v (v^T v) v^T}{(v^T v)^2} = I - 2 \frac{v v^T}{v^T v} + (v^T v) \frac{v v^T}{(v^T v)^2} = P$

Now show (non-trivial) orthogonal projections have (operator 2-norm) norm 1: $||Px||^2 = <Px,Px> =< x, P^T P x> = <x, P P x> = <x, P^2 x> = <x,P x> \leq ||x|| ||P x|| $ so $||Px || \leq ||x||$. Now show equality is achieved by any vector in the range of the projection (in this case, any vector orthogonal to $v$).

Comment: yes, but which norm?

Comment: Projections do not have norm $1$, $P=0$ is also a projection (onto $\{0\}$).

Comment: Fine, non-trivial orthogonal ones.

Comment: To annotate the steps of the operator norm proof, first id efinition of norm, definition of adjoint, symmetry of P, definition of $P^2$, $P$ is a projection then Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. The equality case shows the inequality is tight and thus the operator norm is $1$ since by definition it is the smallest constant $C>0$ such that $||Px|| <= C ||x||$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check the notations of that book first. The authors are probably talking about the spectral-norm. Note that spectral norm is completely different from the frobenius norm. For any square matrix $P$
\begin{align}
||P||_{\text{spectral norm}}=||P||_2=\max_{||x||_2 = 1}||Px||_2=\sigma_{1} &&\{\mbox{spectral norm, $\sigma_1$ is highest singular value}\} \\
||P||_{Frob}=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}|P_{i,j}|^2}=\sqrt{\mathop{trace}\{P^TP\}}=\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sigma_{i}^2 && \{\mbox{frobenius norm, $r$ is rank of $P$}\}
\end{align}

Let $v_1=\frac{v}{||v||_2}$ Let $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{n}$ form a orthonormal basis for $n$ dimensional space so that they are orthogonal to each other and are of unit norm. Let $V=[v_1,\dots,v_n]$ be a $n\times n$ orthonormal matrix. Convince yourself that $$I=VV^T=v_1v_1^T+\dots+v_nv_n^T$$ Note that the matrix you are interested in is $$P=I-v_1v_1^T=v_2v_2^T+\dots+v_nv_n^T$$ Now try to obtain the above results in terms of singular values.

Comment: The spectral norm is given by $\max_{i = 1}^r |\sigma_i|$, i.e. the absolutely greatest eigenvalue, not the greatest eigenvalue. And it is
$$\| P \|_2 = \sup_{x\ne 0} \frac{\|Px\|_2}{\|x\|_2} = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Px\|_2$$
Please correct those mistakes.

Comment: @AlexR Please note that $\sigma_1$ is the highest singular value (as given in the explanation on the right end of the equation in the answer) and not the highest eigenvalue. For a symmetric matrix, the modulus of the eigenvalues gives the singular values. Thanks for the typo about the unit norm on the maximization.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that, the text reaches into the margin on my screen. The answer is fine now (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Letting $A=I-\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}$ . Then $A$ is symmetric, and its eigenvalues are real. Besides $A x = x - v \frac{v^T x}{v^Tv}=\lambda x$ implies that either $x = \alpha v$, (which gives $\lambda=0$) or  $v^T x=0$ which gives $\lambda=1$. Hence it's greater eigenvalue is 1 and, that's the spectral norm.

Comment: This argument only works if there is a vector which is orthogonal to $v$, i.e. only in dimension $n\geq 2$.